# Using JSON and jQuery to update OwlCarousel's content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So hi, I'm a noob :( And I'm working on this single-page project with some galleries for products. The products live inside cards with specific HTML IDs. When I click a card, I want my jQuery script to read the card's HTML ID, and use that string to read a JSON file - which has all galleries. This should populate my gallery with img src tags, which lives inside an OwlCarousel plugin. I got it to work with one gallery, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about getting it to work on the others. Here's my jQuery:

```
// waiting for the click on the .entry-card class

$('.entry-card').click(function() {

  // getting element id; i use this to read the JSON file
  var galleryNumber = $(this).prop('id');

  // firing up bootstrap modal
  $('#modal-gallery').modal();

  // firing up owl carousel inside #modal-gallery
  $('#modal-gallery-carousel').owlCarousel({
  singleItem : true,    
  lazyLoad : true,
  jsonPath : '../data/gallery-entries.json',
  jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess
});

// this is the part i don't get; it's straight out from the owlcarousel tutorial

function customDataSuccess(data) {
  var content = "";
  for (var i in data[galleryNumber]) {
    var img = data[galleryNumber][i].img;
    var alt = data[galleryNumber][i].alt;

    content += "<img src=\"" +img+ "\" alt=\"" +alt+ "\">"
    }
    $('#modal-gallery-carousel').html(content);
  }
});

// waiting for modal to finish closing

$('#modal-gallery').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#modal-gallery-carousel').html('');
  var owl = $('#modal-gallery-carousel').data('owlCarousel');
  owl.destroy();});
```

And the JSON file:

```
{

  // this corresponds to an id tag on the card

  "galeria1" : [
    {
        "img" : "images/buffet-ergo-1.jpg",
        "alt" : "Buffet Ergo"
    },
    {
        "img" : "images/buffet-ergo-1.jpg",
        "alt" : "Buffet Ergo"
    },
    {
        "img" : "images/buffet-ergo-1.jpg",
        "alt" : "Buffet Ergo"
    },
    {
        "img" : "images/buffet-ergo-1.jpg",
        "alt" : "Buffet Ergo"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried repeating the same structure but it won't work; I think the JSON is invalid if I do so. What should I do?